# Массовая проверка FTP доступов

Tags: php, ftp

Есть список FTP доступов, в массиве. Пропускаю его через цикл, но выскакивают ошибки. В чем может быть проблема? Каким образом можно проверять большие списки подключений?

```
foreach($functions->explode_list($path) as $value)
{
  $ftp_connect = explode(";", $value);
  $connect     = ftp_connect($ftp_connect[0]);
  $result_ftp  = ftp_login($connect, $ftp_connect[1], $ftp_connect[2]); 
  ftp_close($connect);

  if($result_ftp) 
  {
    $success++;
  } else {
    $error_connect++;
  }
}
```

тут `$functions->explode_list($path)` массив из списка, разделенных ( ; )
ftp.server1.net;user1;password

Comment: если в списке 1 доступ то все работает, но стоит только добавить еще и возникают ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Пробел добавлялся к паролю, использовал trim() и все заработало как надо.